# Unable to install typewriter package in React js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
npm i typewriter-effect
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: typetest@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.x" from typewriter-effect@2.17.0
npm ERR! node_modules/typewriter-effect
npm ERR!   typewriter-effect@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-03T18_40_11_049Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What's unclear from that output? `typewriter-effect` doesn't support React 17.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the flag --force and then run. typewriter-effect is just using an older version of react. Don't worry about the version conflict just run, for me it worked without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

What i did to solve this issue is that i reinstalled the moduled again and this worked

```
npm i typewriter-effect
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to restart your Terminal to continue installing otherwise it will give error...
I encountered this error today morning... So looking forward you can also solve this